# Filtering REST API call to first result

Tags: javascript, rest, restful-url

I have a question that I feel should be pretty simple to answer, but I cannot find fix anywhere.

I'm querying the Uberchord website for guitar chords (documentation [here](https://api.uberchord.com/))

Here is the URL I'm querying:

[https://api.uberchord.com/v1/chords?nameLike=${variable}](https://api.uberchord.com/v1/chords?nameLike=$%7Bvariable%7D)

Where variable is based on what the user types in.

The nameLike lets fuzzy match between the input and the API (For example, the url for an Fmaj7 chord is F_maj7). This works great, but it returns multiple responses. The first response is *always* the one I want, so I'm trying to just limit the responses to the first one that comes in. So far, I've tried adding a limit or a top filter to the URL to no avail. This is where I'm sure I'm doing something incorrect.

For limit, I've tried:

[https://api.uberchord.com/v1/chords?nameLike=${fmaj7}?limit=1](https://api.uberchord.com/v1/chords?nameLike=$%7Bfmaj7%7D?limit=1)

and

[https://api.uberchord.com/v1/chords?nameLike=${fmaj7}&limit=1](https://api.uberchord.com/v1/chords?nameLike=$%7Bfmaj7%7D&limit=1)

and for top I've done the same two but just replacing limit with top. The first one returns zero responses, while the second returns all responses.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: And just for your future reference. when you have multiple parameters in a query string, you separate them with ampersands: `&`.  The question mark just separates the parameters from the URL.  So, **IF** limit was implemented, it would be `...chords?nameLike=fMaj7&limit=1`.  Also remember that the `${...}` thing is just part of variable substitution.  They aren't part of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't literally "returning multiple responses".  It's just returning an array.  It ALWAYS returns an array, even if there is only one element.  If you only want the first element of that array, then fetch the first element of the array, just like you would with any other array.  After you do the JSON decode:

```
   chord = response[0];
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this within the URL query itself? For example, is there a URL that I could enter that would just give me the array of 1? Apologies, I'm a total novice at how the backend stuff works.

Comment: We can't know that.  It's entirely up to the web site provider.  However, since it is so absolutely trivial to handle this in your Javascript, I doubt they would have gone to the trouble.